# On click on a <link> routing not working but on reloading URL it works

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

Need help!
In my application, I've created a "Link" for navigating from the current page to another page and for that I've used routes and it is kind of working as on the click on the link URL changes but the page is not navigated to the URL specified on the URL bar which is directly accessible when you reload the URL after click.

I'm new to this technology, please let me know if I've gone wrong somewhere.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import InstaGallery from './components/instaGallery.js';
import Home from './components/home'
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom'


function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route path='/instagallery' component={ InstaGallery } />
      </Switch>
    </Router>

  );
}

export default App;
```

**Link.js**

```
<Link to={'/instaGallery'} replace className="menu-anchor"><span><img className="nav-menu-icon" src="https://i.ibb.co/NN8QH7s/Group-1530.png" alt="" />
            {/* <img className="nav-menu-icon-hover" src="https://i.ibb.co/k8kVNk9/Group-2958.png" alt="" /> */}
            HOME</span></Link>
```

**instaGallery.js**

```
//Page to be navigated on click of link
import React from "react";
import $ from "jquery";

class InstaGallery extends React.Component {
  // another function starts

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid no-padd">
        <div className="gallery-wraper">
          <div className="main-grid">
            <p className="p-subtext">Tag us to be featured</p>
            <p className="p">#yallaparty</p>
            <div className="item item1 open" />
            <div className="item item2" />
            <div className="item item3" />
            <div className="item item4" />
            <div className="item item5" />
          </div>
          <div className="description-wraper">
            <div className="pen-description">
              <div className="date">06/03</div>
              <div className="star-ratings-review">
                <div className="star-ratings-gallery"><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span></div>
                <p className="review-text">
                  Thank you so much! You did an amazing job on
                  such short notice. Yalla Party was a major help
                  and I’ll definitely refer you. Good luck for the
                  future!
            </p>
                <p className="text-person">JUMA AL MAJID</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="gallery-btn"><span>
              <button className="gallery-prev-btn">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/hDfxkr6/Group-629.png" alt="" className="gallery-btn-arrow" />
              </button></span><span><button className="gallery-nxt-btn">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/3hpG9rc/Group-628.png" alt="" className="gallery-btn-arrow" />
              </button></span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So when you click on the link, the page url changes but the component doesnt render?

Comment: exactly, cant figure out why..?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try removing `exact` on  with `path="/"`.
2. Add `render` method and return something in `InstaGallery` component.

Question: Why are you importing `jQuery` in `InstaGallery` component?

Comment: Sry..by render you mean..?

Comment: class InstaGallery extends React.Component{
   render() {
      return <div> some example return </div>;
   }
}

Comment: Check it out..now i have added the code which i did not before

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove {} from Link tag like

```
<Link to='/instaGallery' replace className="menu-anchor"><span><img className="nav-menu-icon" src="https://i.ibb.co/NN8QH7s/Group-1530.png" alt="" />
        {/* <img className="nav-menu-icon-hover" src="https://i.ibb.co/k8kVNk9/Group-2958.png" alt="" /> */}
        HOME</span></Link>
```

Comment: No...no luck with that change

Comment: That is valid commenting inside any component.!!